Remove Header and Footer text from dcm meta data file in flutter
I want to remove some header and footer from a dicom or .dcm meta data file so that can able to view dicom/.dcm image file in my Flutter App. can anyone help here to solve this problem.
dicom meta data file link
dicom data file
Note : If you hit this url it will download a file and when open in text editor it will show the header and footer text from top and bottom respectively.

File not readable can you show content of file instead

try open this file in notepad++ or notepad it will open if you are in mac OS try with similar application to see raw data.

@BobSmith plz check changed file path
